# xtion depth image size problem

Tags: ros, xtion, depth-image, camera-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I can't work out why, when I use ROS Topic I'm seeing that the depth frame size is "height: 120xwidth: 160" but the camera info is reporting "height: 480xwidth: 640"

This is causing problems when running depthimage_to_laserscan (as per my question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/190671/depthimage_to_laserscan-image-convertion-error/)

Does anyone know why this might be? Or indeed how I can set it to be correct.

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191468/xtion-depth-image-size-problem/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have solved this but updating the openn2_camera.cpp file to list out the supported depth modes of the attached device. Then, for now,hardcoding to the mode I want. This also solved the problem I was having with depthimage_to_laserscan [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/190671/depthimage_to_laserscan-image-convertion-error/)

Code is - should anyone want to know (note the resolution needs to be set between the create() mentod call and the start() menthod call. You can't change the resolution on the fly:

```
    /*
 * Software License Agreement (BSD License)
 *
 *  Copyright (c) 2011 Willow Garage, Inc.
 *    Radu Bogdan Rusu <rusu@willowgarage.com>
 *    Suat Gedikli <gedikli@willowgarage.com>
 *    Patrick Mihelich <mihelich@willowgarage.com>
 *
 *  All rights reserved.
 *
 *  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 *  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 *  are met:
 *
 *   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
 *     copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
 *     disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided
 *     with the distribution.
 *   * Neither the name of Willow Garage, Inc. nor the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 *  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 *  "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 *  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
 *  FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 *  COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
 *  INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
 *  BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 *  LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
 *  CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 *  LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
 *  ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 *  POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 */

#include "OpenNI.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <camera_info_manager/camera_info_manager.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/distortion_models.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace openni;

// the following function was copied from openni_camera
sensor_msgs::CameraInfoPtr getDefaultCameraInfo(int width, int height, double f) 
{
  sensor_msgs::CameraInfoPtr info = boost::make_shared<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>();

  info->width  = width;
  info->height = height;

  //std::cout << "info->width: " << width << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "info->height: " << height << std::endl;
  // No distortion
  info->D.resize(5, 0.0);
  info->distortion_model = sensor_msgs::distortion_models::PLUMB_BOB;

  // Simple camera matrix: square pixels (fx = fy), principal point at center
  info->K.assign(0.0);
  info->K[0] = info->K[4] = f;
  info->K[2] = (width / 2) - 0.5;
  // Aspect ratio for the camera center on Kinect (and other devices?) is 4/3
  // This formula keeps the principal point the same in VGA and SXGA modes
  info->K[5] = (width * (3./8.)) - 0.5;
  info->K[8] = 1.0;

  // No separate rectified image plane, so R = I
  info->R.assign(0.0);
  info->R[0] = info->R[4] = info->R[8] = 1.0;

  // Then P=K(I|0) = (K|0)
  info->P.assign(0.0);
  info->P[0]  = info->P[5] = f; // fx, fy
  info->P[2]  = info->K[2];     // cx
  info->P[6]  = info->K[5];     // cy
  info->P[10] = 1.0;

  return info;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "openni2_camera");
    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");

    ROS_INFO("creating image_transport... this might take a while...");
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    // Initialize Publisher for depth and rgb image and advertise
    image_transport::Publisher image_pub_depth = it.advertise("depth/image_raw", 1);
    image_transport::Publisher image_pub_rgb = it.advertise("rgb/image_raw", 1);
    ros::Publisher pub_depth_camera_info = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>("depth/camera_info", 1);
    ros::Publisher pub_rgb_camera_info = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>("rgb/camera_info", 1);

    string rgb_info_url, depth_info_url;
  nh.param("rgb_camera_info_url", rgb_info_url, string());
  nh.param("depth_camera_info_url", depth_info_url, string());

    // Load the saved calibrations, if they exist
  boost::shared_ptr<camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager> rgb_info_manager_ = \
            boost::make_shared<camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager>(nh, "rgb", rgb_info_url);
  boost::shared_ptr<camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager> depth_info_manager_  = \
            boost::make_shared<camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager>(nh,  "depth",  depth_info_url);

    if (!rgb_info_manager_->isCalibrated())
    ROS_WARN("Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.");
  if (!depth_info_manager_->isCalibrated())
    ROS_WARN("Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.");

    try 
    {
        Status initStatus = OpenNI::initialize();
        if (initStatus != STATUS_OK)
        {
            ROS_ERROR("Device could not be initialized because %s", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
            return -1;
        }
        openni::Device device;
        Status openStatus = device.open(ANY_DEVICE);
        while ( openStatus != STATUS_OK ) {
            ROS_ERROR("Device could not be opened because %s", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
            return -1;
        }

        openni::VideoStream depthStream;
        openni::VideoStream rgbStream;
        depthStream.create(device, SENSOR_DEPTH);
        rgbStream.create(device, SENSOR_COLOR);
        
        // List the depth modes supported by the device
        cout << "Available depth modes" << endl;
        const openni::SensorInfo* sinfo = device.getSensorInfo(openni::SENSOR_DEPTH); // select index=4 640x480, 30 fps, 1mm
        const openni::Array< openni::VideoMode>& modesDepth = sinfo->getSupportedVideoModes();
        
        for (int i = 0; i<modesDepth.getSize(); i++) 
        {
            printf("%i: %ix%i, %i fps, %i format\n", i, modesDepth[i].getResolutionX(), modesDepth[i].getResolutionY(),
            modesDepth[i].getFps(), modesDepth[i].getPixelFormat()); //PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_1_MM = 100, PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM
        }
        
        //openStatus = depthStream.setVideoMode(modesDepth[4]);
        openStatus = depthStream.setVideoMode(modesDepth[0]); // TO-DO - pass this through as a parameter
        
        if (openni::STATUS_OK != openStatus)
        {
            cout << "error: depth format not supported..." << endl;
        }
        
        depthStream.start();
        rgbStream.start();

        openni::VideoStream** streams = new openni::VideoStream*[2];
        streams[0] = &depthStream;
        streams[1] = &rgbStream;

        cv::Mat depthImage;
        cv::Mat rgbImage;

        cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_depth(new cv_bridge::CvImage);
        cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_rgb(new cv_bridge::CvImage);
        ROS_INFO("Everything set up... lets stream some images");
        while (ros::ok()) 
        {
        int changedIndex;
        OpenNI::waitForAnyStream( streams, 2, &changedIndex );
            // capture time as close to recording as possible
            ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
            switch (changedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    openni::VideoFrameRef depthFrame;
                    depthStream.readFrame( &depthFrame);
                    if ( depthFrame.isValid() ) 
                    {
                    depthImage = cv::Mat(depthStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionY(),
                      depthStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionX(),
                      CV_16U, (char*)depthFrame.getData() );
                    //depthImage.convertTo( depthImage, CV_8U );

                        // convert cv::Mat into cv_bridge image
                        cv_ptr_depth->image = depthImage;
                        cv_ptr_depth->encoding = "16UC1";
                        cv_ptr_depth->header.frame_id = "/openni2_depth_frame";
                        cv_ptr_depth->header.stamp = time;
                        image_pub_depth.publish(cv_ptr_depth->toImageMsg());

                        sensor_msgs::CameraInfoPtr info = getDefaultCameraInfo(640, 480, 570.3422241210938);
                        //std::cout << "sensor_msgs::CameraInfoPtr: " << std::endl;
                        
                        //std::cout << "depthStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionY(): " << depthStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionY() << std::endl;
                        //std::cout << "depthStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionX() " << depthStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionX() << std::endl;
                        
                        info->K[2] -= 5; // cx
                        info->K[5] -= 4; // cy
                        info->P[2] -= 5; // cx
                        info->P[6] -= 4; // cy
                        // Fill in header
                        info->header.stamp    = time;
                        info->header.frame_id = "/openni2_depth_frame";
                        pub_depth_camera_info.publish(info);
                  }
                } break;
                case 1: 
                {
                    openni::VideoFrameRef rgbFrame;
                    rgbStream.readFrame( &rgbFrame);
                    if ( rgbFrame.isValid() ) 
                    {
                        rgbImage = cv::Mat(rgbStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionY(),
                  rgbStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionX(),
                  CV_8UC3, (char*)rgbFrame.getData() );

                        // convert cv::Mat into cv_bridge image
                        cv_ptr_rgb->image = rgbImage;
                        cv_ptr_rgb->encoding = "rgb8";
                        cv_ptr_rgb->header.frame_id = "/openni2_rgb_frame";
                        cv_ptr_rgb->header.stamp = time;
                        image_pub_rgb.publish(cv_ptr_rgb->toImageMsg());    

                        sensor_msgs::CameraInfoPtr info = getDefaultCameraInfo(640, 480, 525);
                        // Fill in header
                        info->header.stamp    = time;
                        info->header.frame_id = "/openni2_rgb_frame";
                        pub_rgb_camera_info.publish(info);
                    }
                } break;
                default:
                    ROS_WARN("Index %i is neither a depth nor a rgb image stream", changedIndex);
            }
        ros::spinOnce();
        }
    }

    catch ( std::exception& ) {
        ROS_ERROR("catching error.... got it!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1